# ValueError: could not convert string to float: (115.985)

Tags: python, string, scale

[image]I'm receiving data from a scale. When I receive data from that scale, the form is like this : `b' 1G      15.985lb \r\n'` So I want to keep only my `115.985`. The b' 1G      15.985lb \r\n' is not hard coded it's byte returned by my scale this is why I need to decode (It will be 115.985 if you try it because of the 1 before the G but it's an other problem for later for now I juste want to put my 115.985 to a float) When I receive the data from the scale it's in Bytes so I use `serialString.decode('utf-8')` to transform it into a string so I can keep only the number with : `finalweight = re.sub('[^\d\.]', '', serialString_decode)`

But I need this number to be in float so I can use it in an inventory to do some math with it. So I try to use : `finalweight = float(finalweight)` but I keep getting this error : `ValueError: could not convert string to float':

My string don't have any ',' or space. Try alot of thing but can't find what's wrong with my code.

```
import re

serialString = "b' 1G      15.985lb \r\n'"
serialString_decode=serialString.decode('utf-8') #Decode bytes to str 
finalweight = re.sub('[^\d\.]', '', serialString_decode) # Keep number
finalweight = float(finalweight) # try to put the string in float
print(finalweight)
```

Have a float so I can do math with

Comment: A likely improvement is to hard-code the value of `serialString`, so we have runnable code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I hard coded and simplified the code. Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: Please supply the missing `import`s as well.

Comment: after you edited the code it should be `serialString = b'1G ....'`. and I tried to run your code, it ran successfully. Even though the answer I got is 115.985 and not 15.985.

Comment: Yes i'ts an other problem that I will solve later, it's because of the 1 before the G for now I just want to do math with my 115.985

Comment: You should be using Python 3 for everything now, Python 2 has been sunsetted.

Comment: I'm in python 3, the data in my real code is not hard coded

Answer (score 1):

It prints 115.985 in python2.7 macOS Mojave. Your code wont work with python3 as `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'` in python3.

[image]

Here is your solution for python3

[image]

Comment: So is there any solution in python3 ?

Comment: I need to do the decode because in fact b' 1G      15.985lb \r\n' is not hardcoded but Bytes retuned by my scale this is why I need to decode then I keep only the number.

Comment: That's a separate problem. Please accept this and then we can look at that problem. Decode won't solve that problem if there is any

Comment: It's accepted here is the error I have with my bytes data receive from my scale ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: Sorry now it is

Comment: Please share the a byte data that we can use to reproduce this error.